# Is possible to update a project that has been installed from the archive file?

Tags: 8, updating, composer

I'm very new to composer, I've only used it to install the occasional necessary library for our D8 projects. At each Drupal update I normally run

```
drush up drupal
```

Which (among other things) replaces the vendor folder and composer.json, so on sites with library dependencies, I need to re-run

```
composer require [library]
```

Aware of the touted benefits of Composer as a dependency manager, I want to use composer to maintain our Drupal projects. However I've run into issues, namely that

```
composer update
```

or
    composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
both give me "Nothing to install or update". After some reading, I found this resource https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project. With this unzip, if I run

```
composer install
```

I get the correct latest version of Drupal installed in ./web. But when I use the yaml from the template composer.json file in my own composer.json file I still get "Nothing to install or update".

My folder structure is identical to the .zip distribution, so /core and /vendor and /sites etc are all in the same folder, so I have obviously adjusted the composer.json file according. But it doesn't matter what I do, I just get
"Nothing to install or update"
"Nothing to install or update"
"Nothing to install or update"

So, I'm beginning to think that composer update with or without dependencies REQUIRES YOU TO HAVE INSTALL THE DRUPAL 8 PROJECT WITH COMPOSER TO BEGIN WITH.

Is that right? If so, then I can move on.
If not then I need to know what I'm doing wrong. Right now it's not a big deal and I can manage the update process, but it seems each new project requires more and more non-core libraries, so I know composer will save me a lot of time in the future.

TL;DR - Can someone give me a kickstart to configuring my EXISTING, WORKING PRODUCTION SITES so I can use composer to update them, the usual ReadMe's don't seem to work properly with sites that weren't also installed with composer.

Answer (score 8):

I got this working, I was very close but [removing /vendor and composer.lock](https://www.drupal.org/node/2813545#comment-11700753) was what helped in the end.
Here are the steps from the top:

1. add the line
           "drupal/core": "~8.1"
   to the 'require' statement (or update it to whatever version you require - in my case ^8.0 - latest Drupal 8 release).
2. Remove the drupal/core line from the 'replace' statement.
3. Add the following line somewhere (at the end? I believe this should replace the existing repositories statement, [more information here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies).
   ):

   ```
   "repositories": { 
       "drupal": {
           "type": "composer",
           "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8" 
       }
   }
   ```
4. Remove the /vendor folder
5. Remove the composer.lock file
6. Run your core update as follows

   ```
   composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
   ```

Comment: You can add a repository via the command-line by running `composer config repositories.drupal composer https://packages.drupal.org/8`. Also if you are managing everything with composer you can start doing `composer require drupal/<modulename>` instead of manually modifying composer.json. Also, running `composer update` will update your composer.lock file so you don't need to delete it. If you're using Drupal 8.0.x, then you can't really manage things with composer without composer manager.

Comment: @mradcliffe I recently converted a D8 site from drush management to composer management.  Nuking `compsoser.lock` did seem to be a necessary step (still don't know why) to get this to work.

Comment: Two notes.  Personally, I like to pin core to a precise version so I am never surprised (eg,`"drupal/core": "8.2.5",`) to prevent update hook surprises.  Also, adding the `extra` section from the page you reference ensures modules/themes/etc end up where you want them.

Comment: The drupal-merge-plugin might help with not having to delete vendor or the lock file. I use that to bridge the gap between drush make and composer since I have some problems with using composer directly.

Comment: Once I get the hang of what the correct yaml is, I'll look into the correct composer commands. Thanks mradcliffe

Comment: @mpdonadio - I would assume that modules and themes just automatically go to /modules and /themes, no?

Comment: @mradcliffe - 8.2.6 was released yesterday, and I didn't need to remove .lock or /vendor to update, 'composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies' worked as expected.

Comment: @RominRonin Only when you specify the locations, https://www.drupal.org/node/2718229

Comment: If only i had found your answer before. I’ve struggled hours to find a solution. Do I have to change this manually each time I want to update or was it an issue with composer.json ?